# Ubuntu cosmic is not supported

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, prerequisites

I was following this online guide of hyperledger:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html#ubuntu

this is the guide how i can download pre requisites

[1st command is sucessfully run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8ujt.png)

it is to install .sh file

and when i run second command the error comes like this

[Error: Ubuntu cosmic not supported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqPII.png)

Comment: Hyperledger composer should only be used for education purposes into the business domain of digital assets. If you are planning on doing anything more than you should invest your time in using hyperledger fabric directly and understand it's programming models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs#ubuntu
It seems though the version of Ubuntu is not supported. 16.04 - Xenial Xerus and 18.04 - Bionic Beaver are. These are both LTS (Long Term Support) releases. The intermediate releases are only supported for 9 months.

Comment: Thanks for the reply what is the alternate ? i should go for the manual installation ?

Comment: If you have no other dependencies, go for 18.04. It is supported by Canonical, the company behind Ubuntu, for the next few years and it is possible to use Hyperledger on it. I imagine in the next few months Hyperledger will also support 20.04 which is the next LTS release of Ubuntu and there will be a clear migration path between 18.04 and 20.04. I would only pursue a manual installation if I had competing dependencies and no other options.

Comment: In a similar situation, MS SQL Server 2017 is supported on Ubuntu 16.04, I can make it work on 18.04, but nothing later. I have tried compiling the dependent component from source but I can't make it work properly. The result is 18.04 is the latest version of Ubuntu I can use until MS update SQL Server to be compliant with later versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: It's worth noting, Composer is deprecated and no longer being supported, so you won't see any new updates for it